# Deriving the power reduction formula for $\cos^n\theta$ and $\sin^n\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Our class has just started discussing complex numbers and I have a this as a homework.

I am trying to show that:

$$\cos^n\theta = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{r=0}^\frac{n-1}{2}\binom{n}{r}\cos[(n-2r)\theta]$$

for odd positive integers $n$.

We haven't discussed $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ yet, so I assume that it is not necessary. I started my solution as follows:

$$\cos^n\theta=\frac{[(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)]^n}{2^n}$$

After using binomial expansion and power laws, I eventually reached this in my solution:

$$\cos^n\theta = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}[\cos\{(n-2r)\theta\}+i\sin\{(n-2r)\theta\}]$$

As I plugged in some odd positive integers for $n$, I noticed that the $i\sin\{(n-2r)\theta\}$ terms cancel out, while the $\cos\{(n-2r)\theta\}$ terms are doubled.

Essentially I have found my proof however I am having difficulty expressing this explicitly. How should I go about finishing this proof?

Comment: Compare the $r$ and $n-r$ terms.

Comment: *A priori* as the result is real, the imaginary part must be zero, so just ignore it.

Comment: Do you know the Tchebytchev polynomials ?

Comment: @max8128 I don't know about Thebytchev polynomials. I tried reading about it just now but I don't know how it would apply here (I probably did not understand it well enough).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes thinking about it now, I think comparing $r$ and $n-r$ terms is the way to go. Thank you.